# How can we prove that p <=> q ≡ (p∧q)∨(~p∧~q) without using truth table?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I tried using biconditional law then negation but still not able to get the answer.

Comment: Use proof by contradiction...

Comment: Are you treating $\iff$ as primitive or defined as $(x \implies y) \land (y \implies x)$ or something else? Can you please list the axioms and rules of inference that you are using or provide a link to a description of the axioms and rules of inference that you are using?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet we can use Idempotent law, commutative law, conditonal law, de morgans law etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two lines of the following can be taken as replacements of $\ p\iff q\ $, $\ p\Rightarrow q\ $ and $\ q\Rightarrow p\ $ by their definitions, and the rest are de Morgan's laws.  It also uses the fact that expressions obtained by replacing parenthesized subexpressions with equivalent ones are themselves equivalent. If there are any operations in the argument that aren't in the bag of tricks you're allowed to use, then, of course, you'll need to adapt the argument to eliminate them.
\begin{align}
(p \Leftrightarrow q)&\equiv (p\Rightarrow q)\wedge(q\Rightarrow p)\\
&\equiv (q\vee\neg p)\wedge(p\vee\neg q)\\
&\equiv ((q\vee\neg p)\wedge p)\vee ((q\vee\neg p)\wedge \neg q)\\
&\equiv((q\wedge p)\vee (\neg p\wedge p))\vee((q\wedge\neg q)\vee(\neg p\wedge\neg q))\\
&\equiv (q\wedge p)\vee(\neg p\wedge\neg q)\\
\end{align}